# Identify this succulent?

Tags: identification, houseplants

[image]

Can you help me identify this plant?

Answer (score 2):

Moonstones a species of Pachyphtum. Also known as Sugaralmond plant. The meaning of the name Pachyphytum oviferum is thick plant bearing eggs. The stems (20 cm long, 1 cm thick) rise then fall with about 15 leaves. These leaves are 3 to 5 cm long, 1.8 to 3 cm wide and 8 to 17 mm thick.

Leaves are pale blue-green to bluish-purple, looking like a sugared almond confection.[1]

The inflorescence consists of a 30 cm stem bearing scarlet, bell-shaped flowers

Tip:
A good way to tell if your moonstone plant needs watering is to examine the leaves. If they appear plump and feel firm, the plant doesn't need to be watered. If the leaves appear wrinkly or feel soft, it's time to water. Since overwatering is the main cause of most succulent problems, it's better to underwater than to water too frequently.